# Is there any REST API to check if blob exists in a container

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-blob-storage

Is there any REST API to check if blob exist or not in a container?  I know we can achieve tis with sdk , but I have a requirement where I need to check via URI along with SAS token (using Powershell).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**By using powershell and Rest API**

You will have to use the `invoke-webrequest` and `-method` head
You can hit this [endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/get-blob-properties)
You can check the server response - in case you receive **404** that indicates the the blob doesn't exist.

If the blob exists it will return headers of the blob.

**Sample code :**

```
try
{
Invoke-WebRequest -Method Head "https://svijaystorage.blob.core.windows.net/svijay-deploy/B.XML?sv=<SV>&st=2020-10-21T15:55:17Z&spr=https&sig=<SIG>" 
}
catch
{
if( $_.exception -like "*404*")
{
Write-Host "Blob Doesn't Exist" -ForegroundColor Yellow
}
}
```

**Output when the blob is existent :**
[image]

**Output when the blob is non-existent :**
[image]

Comment: @harshit  - I have updated the answer with a sample  code

Comment: $newUrl =https://<storageAccount>.blob.core.windows.net/<container>/myblob.out
?sv=2019-07-07&sr=c&sig=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&spr=https&se=2020-10-30T11%3A00%3A00Z&sp=rwdl

invoke-webrequest -method get $newUrl

Error:
Invoke-WebRequest:
Bad Request
Bad Request - Invalid URL
HTTP Error 400. The request URL is invalid.